# Terminal screenshot generator

Tags: code, terminal-output

I would like to document work in console while I also think that bitmap images are not the best way to do it. They do not scale well and after all what I am trying to document is text. Therefore I began to wonder whether there is something that could embed text provided into latex formatting which rendered would resemble terminal output.

My intention is to document interaction with a microcontroller using serial line terminal emulator. It typically means single line command followed by a few lines of response.

[image]

Comment: You can treat terminal output just like verbatim text or code. Hence, packages like listings are what you want. It is even possible to have white text on a black background with the right settings.

Comment: this is a question where a screenshot of what you want to emulate *would* be helpful.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you are right. I want to document command line interaction with a device. Nothing fancy like ASCII art required here.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to render Terminal Output in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5277/5764)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Something like this? (Actually stolen from `tcolorbox` manual and slightly changed ;-))

A `verbatim` input environment is necessary in my point of view, so a `listings` etc. style approach might be very convenient.

The `tcolorbox` wrappers of `listings` provide nice features to improve the look of the surroundings of a `listings` environment.

Use the `every listings line=` option to provide some information like `hostname` or `user name` etc, depending on your special `terminal` style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{commandshell}{colback=black,colupper=white,colframe=yellow!75!black,
listing only,listing options={language=sh},
every listing line={\textcolor{red}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries DeathStar \$> }}}

\begin{document}
\begin{commandshell}
ls -al
cd /usr/lib
rm -rf *
\end{commandshell}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is nice, but the command prompt is fake and fixed... do you know if there is a verbatim environment able to accept ANSI color codes and unicode char? Copying and pasting (even from a `script` log) [this terminal](http://imgur.com/hvpHX5f) will not work...

Comment: @christianHupfer maybe he would like to have something like c:\> cd temp next line c:\temp> dir and all after > has another color....only guessed

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger: Perhaps, but he might ... or he would or ... it could be that ... Interestingly you and Rmano complain about what my solution does not provide, but not about that the question is not **clear** at all ;-)

Comment: No, I do not complain. If you feel so I am sorry. I have tried to provide another solution....but it fits not my own needs.

Answer (score 4):

[Knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) can show not only outputs from R, but also from another engines. May be this is not the ideal approach to mimic a real screenshot,  but can show the true outputs of a `bash` shell typing only the commands.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[black]{sourcecodepro}
\begin{document}
\section*{Top Linux utilities:}
\subsection*{fortune}
<<eval=F,background='lightyellow',>>=
me@mypc$ fortune 
@
\noindent\fcolorbox{green}{black}{
\parbox{\linewidth}{\color{white}\sffamily
<<engine='bash', echo=F, results="asis">>=
fortune fortunes
@
}}
\subsection*{apt-get moo}
<<engine='bash'>>=
apt-get moo
@
\subsection*{cowsay}
<<eval=F>>=
cowsay "Hello, World"
@
<<engine='bash', background='lightcyan', comment="",echo=F>>=
cowsay "Hello, World"
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is wicked cool! Although bit of an overkill for my actual purpose, I have spent some time playing with knitr (another reason for  moving from SAS to R ;) ). Thanks for expanding my horizons.

Comment: @Mr.Tao You're welcome.  LaTeX or R are both woderful , but discover that one can LaTeX+R  turn  both tools in invaluable resources.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\def\CS#1{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcblisting{commandshell}{colback=black,colupper=white,colframe=yellow!75!black,
listing only,listing options={style=tcblatex,language=sh},
every listing line={\textcolor{red}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries DeathStar \$> }}}

\begin{document}
\begin{commandshell}
ls -al
cd /usr/lib
rm -rf *
\end{commandshell}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=ä,numbers=none,framerule=0.0pt]
ä\colorbox{black}{%
  \parbox{5.7in}{\color{white} C:\CS{}>cd \CS{}Python27 \\ C:\CS{}Python27>cd scripts \\ C:\CS{}Python27\CS{}Scripts>easy\_install pygmentize}
   }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The solution of Christian is still included.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: while well-intended, the example with "ordinary" serif type does not show up well at all on some monitors -- the thin strokes nearly disappear.  (always worse with reverse video.)  and although a proportionally spaced monowidth font would improve that situation, it's often the case with terminal output that the strict alignment in adjacent lines is very helpful (if not absolutely necessary) for quick comprehension.