# Display Ubuntu terminal output

Tags: terminal-output

I am writing a memoir in latex. I have lot of output from Ubuntu terminal and I have tried to put in verbatim, but this is really not pretty. I was wandering if there is a latex tip to put Linux terminal output in latex and make it pretty.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Some like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307129/terminal-screenshot-generator/307130#307130, perhaps???

Comment: Try looking into the {tag:listings} or {tag:minted} packages.

Comment: @ArunDebray Unrelated tip: `[tag:listings]` makes a link to [tag:listings].

Comment: If you are not satisfied with the prettiness of packages like `listings` or `minted`, you can always include a screenshot of the original terminal output instead.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thank you; I was misremembering the syntax.