# How to preprocess code inside a listings (or fancyvrb) environment?

Tags: listings, verbatim, fancyvrb

Suppose I want to make a `shell` environment to typeset examples of shell commands. I'd like to automate some details to remain consistent. For example, I need to automatically put a '$' at the beginning of the first line, so a piece of code like:

```
\begin{shell}
cat nothing > /dev/null
cat: nothing: No such file or directory
\end{shell}
```

would be typeset as if the code were written as:

```
$ cat nothing > /dev/null
cat: nothing: No such file or directory
```

This idea can be expanded. For example, the command line could be typeset differently from the command output, or I may want to intercept a final `\` to indent the subsequent lines, and so on...

In other words, I would like to *preprocess* the verbatim content of the environment before passing it to the actual `lstlisting` environment.

Is this even possible? How to do it?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307130/36296 , the `every listing line` option may be helpful to get the $ at every line.

Comment: @samcarter Wouldn't that put `$` on every line, and not just the first line?

Comment: @Teepeemm You're right, I misunderstood your question. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

This could quickly become too complicated for use, but I composed it to mention that the `verbatimbox` environments allow limited preprocessing of their content with an optional argument.

However, in this case, I am just using `\active` characters to intercept and test the input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,ifthen,xcolor}
\let\CatCode\catcode
\let\aCtive\active
\let\LCC c
\CatCode`c=\aCtive %
\def c{\Ctest}
\CatCode`c=11 %
\def\Ctest#1#2#3{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1#2}{at}}%
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{:}}{\rmfamily\LCC#1#2#3}{\$ \textcolor{red}{\LCC#1#2#3}}}%
    {\LCC#1#2#3}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}
cat nothing > /dev/null
cat: nothing: No such file or directory
other stuff with a c in it
\end{verbbox}
verbatimbox without active c: \fbox{\theverbbox}

\CatCode`c=\active
\begin{verbbox}
cat nothing > /dev/null
cat: nothing: No such file or directory
other stuff with a c in it
\end{verbbox}
\CatCode`c=11 
verbatimbox with active c: \fbox{\theverbbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Reading the documentation of `verbatimbox`, if I understand correctly, the customization is limited to the execution of some code *before* each line, right? So how to generically glob everything up to the next newline, process the line contents and then typeset the result?

Comment: @gigabytes That interpretation is, unfortunately, correct.  It can execute code prior to the verbatim line.  To get inside the line, I can only think of the `\active` character approach to do so.

Comment: Well I can immagine a command that can glob everything up to the first newline and process that. How could it be done?