# Bash Syntax Hightlighting in a Tex File

Tags: syntax-highlighting, bash

I've got the question if there is a possibility to auto-highlight Bash syntax in a compiled Tex File. Is there a package that has a function to accomplish that? Thanks in advance, ADDB.

Comment: Packages `listings`, `minted` and `tcolorbox` (with its `listings` or `minted` libraries) are able to do this, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307130/31729, for example

Comment: A simple search for "bash listings" reveals several Q&A regarding this topic.